# How to update sub document in mongodb php using new php driver library

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I am using this php libarary http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/

I have a collection posts and in its one document i am adding multiple comments that i can add new comments like this

```
$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->project->posts;
$id = '5799a81fa60afa2010001838';
$result = $collection->updateOne(

     ["_id" => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($id)],

     ['$push' => [
             "comments" => ['id'=>1,'name' => 'sohss','comm'=>'I like it']
                 ]
     ]

     );
```

Now how can update any specific comment i have tried like this but no success

```
$updateResult = $collection->updateOne(
                ['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($id),'comments'],
                ['$set' =>  
                            ['comments'=>[0]=>
                                        ['name'=>'123']
                            ]
                ]
            );
```

Whats the proper syntax to update sub document.

The structure of the document is as follows:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5799a81fa60afa2010001838"),
"title" : "test",
"comments" : [ 
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "soh",
        "comm" : "I like it"
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "sohss",
        "comm" : "I like it"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show the current structure of the document and also the structure of the updated document

Comment: And how should the updated document look like?

Comment: I want to update field of  "comm" : "I like it" in sub document how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

We need to use the $ positional operator to update the specific field in subdocument eg if i want to update the name in subdocument of id 3 we can do like this

```
$updateResult = $collection->updateOne(
                ['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($id),'comments.id'=>3],
                ['$set' =>  
                            ['comments.$.name'=> 'Sohail anwar'

                            ]
                ]
            );
```